# Is there a way to save "Script Execution Progress" in a file?

Tags: qlikview

Is there any way I could save the "Script Execution Progress" in file?

When I tried the following code, it generated a empty file.

```
C:> "C:\PROGRAM FILES\QLIKVIEW\QV.EXE" /R "C:\Q1.qvw" >> "log\VistoriasEmergenciais.log"
```

Thanks

Comment: You might want to try [Generate Logfile](https://community.qlik.com/thread/102310) and then reload. Another [link](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/qlikview-scripting/9781782171669/ch08s05.html)

Comment: That is a cool option!! but I was looking for something I could edit and input just what I think is necessary, do you think I can do something like this?